# RestSharp portable add json body from userinput field

Tags: c#, json, rest, uwp, restsharp

in my UWP App, the user can enter a json body in a textfield and set it as body in a POST Rest-Request via restsharp portable.

So the user types this into a textbox (value is bound to requestBody):

```
{  "string": "Hello World"}
```

and then I add the string to the request:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", requestBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

The body was added, but not correct. 
The Server doesn´t parse the incoming json body.

I don´t know what´s the problem, but I think some characters a not encoded correctly.

Has anyone managed it to add a json body in this way?

---

This solution works:

```
var b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(requestBody);
request.AddJsonBody(b);
```

but that´s not the clean way

Comment: What is the full request definition? Did you also add `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;`?

Comment: The RestRequest class has not member RequestFormat

Comment: Could you past the whole code?

Comment: var restClient = new RestClient(baseUri);
var request = new RestRequest(path, Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", requestBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
ar response = await restClient.Execute<Object>(request);

Comment: Have you tried Microsoft.Net.HttpClient, seem a bit more straight forward as ResharpPortable is not longer maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example of code that has worked for me:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost");
var request = new RestRequest("pathtoservice", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{ \"Some\": \"Data\" }", ParameterType.RequestBody);
var result = client.Execute(request);
```

For completeness, when using the RestSharp Portable the above would be:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost");
var request = new RestRequest("pathtoservice", Method.POST);
var requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"Some\": \"Data\" }");
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", requestBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var result = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: In the restsharp.portable library the RestRequest class has not member RequestFormat

Comment: Aha, wasn't aware you were using .NET Core/Portable (while it was in the title of the question...).
Maybe could try to UTF-8 encode the body:
`var someBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);` and use that in the AddParameter method.

Comment: That works:
 var someBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
                request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", someBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);   thank you